# How can I copy the embedded resource into output directory as well?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment, msbuild

I have a rules file for workflow within my solution and its properties are

> **Build Action** = Embedded Resource,
>
> **Copy to Output Directory** = Copy always

I can't change the build action to Content, otherwise the workflow compilation won't work. However, I need the file to be deployed to the output folder and it seems not to work. Is there anything I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is set as an embedded resource, it should be embedded directly into the EXE as far as I know.

Regardless, you can add a post-build action which just copies the file into the output folder if that's the way it needs to work: right-click the project in Solution Explorer and click Properties, then in the Build Events tab you can specify what files you want to be copied where.