# Copy asset files to /Debug

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, copy

Using VS 2008 I want to copy files in the project folder to the /Debug folder on each build.

How can you do that?

There's [an answer for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014207/copy-to-output-directory-copies-folder-structure-but-only-want-to-copy-files) but it doesn't work for VC++ (xml parse error on project load)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This works in .Net development.

In your solution explorer select the file you wish to have copied. Then in the properties panel under "Build action" select "Copy to output".

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time since I last used VC++, but I guess you still have possibility to define post-build steps, e.g. to copy files into the output folder (debug or release). Check the property page for your project ("Build Events") and you should be able to find it there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing the settings for "Copy to output directory" should work. There are special cases, like embedding the thing (see this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236867/how-can-i-copy-the-embedded-resource-into-output-directory-as-well)), but normally it should be just fine.

Comment: They're actually not part of the "project" perse, so that the VS workspace remains uncluttered.  But they do sit in the same folder as the source files on disk (from sub directory /assets).  What I want to do is write a command that copies everything in (source code dir)/assets/* to /Debug..